# C++ split/partition large array into smaller ones

Tags: c++, arrays

This will be my 1st question to StackOverflow. The problem that I would like to resolve i how to split one large array filled wit values into smaller ones.
Is this even good approach to do so ?

The array has 10000 elements and I would like to split it to 8 smaller ones.

Some code below:
How I have generated the array

```
double* GenerateRandomArray(UI nSize){
    double* rndArr=nullptr;
    rndArr = new double [baseArrSize];
    double randVal=0.0;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(low_val, high_val);
    std::default_random_engine rndEng;
    for(int i=0; i<baseArrSize; ++i){
        randVal = unif(rndEng);
        rndArr[i] = randVal;
    }

    delete [] rndArr;
```

}

Now my second function should split/partition this array to smaller ones or perhaps I should create additional 8 functions that would get the proper parts of the base array copied into their sub-arrays?

Some code on how I captured the first part of array:

```
double* PartitionArray1(double* rootArr){
    rootArr = new double [baseArrSize];
    const UI splitVal = baseArrSize/8;
    double* arr0=nullptr;

    arr0 = new double[splitVal];
    for(UI i=0; i<splitVal; i++){
            arr0[i] = rootArr[i];
    }
    for(UI j=0; j<splitVal; ++j)
        std::cout << arr0[j] << " ";
    return arr0;
```

}

This seems to work - as checking the arr0 it has 1250 elemnts from the base array.

Two questions that I have regarding this are:

1. How to do this in the next stps? i.e. I have function to create a second sub-array, don't know how to start passing the arguments from a certain point of the base array up to another one.

   arr1 = new double[splitVal];
       for(UI i=0; i
2. Is this even a valid approach ? Perhaps it would be better to generate a large vector and then split it to arrays ?

Thanks

Comment: *"This seems to work"* - the memory leak at `rootArr` notwithstanding ?

Comment: The function takes `rootArr` as a parameter and the first thing it does is overwrite the pointer. Are you sure it works?

Comment: Don't use pointers and manual memory handling for arrays. For dynamic "arrays" use `std::vector`.

Comment: As for your problem, why not use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into those points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the comments.
I have done this in a bit of a different way than suggested:

```
double* SplitFirstArray_1st(double *arr0){
            const UI arrSize = baseElements/4;
    std::cout << "\n1st split: \n";
    double *arrSplited1=nullptr;
    arrSplited1 = new double [arrSize];
    for(UI i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
        arrSplited1 = arr0;
    }

    for(UI j=0; j< arrSize; ++j){
        std::cout << arrSplited1[j] << " ";
        }
    return arrSplited1;
    delete [] arrSplited1, arr0;
```

}

Similar way is done in the next functions, i.e.

```
double* SplitThirdArray_3rd(double *arr0){
    const UI arrSize = baseElements/4;
    std::cout << "\n3rd split: \n";
    double *arrSplited3=nullptr;
    arrSplited3 = new double [arrSize];
    double *arr3splitedStart = &arr0[arrSize+25];
    for(UI i=0; i<arrSize; i++){
        arrSplited3 = arr3splitedStart;
    }
    for(UI j=0; j< arrSize; ++j){
        std::cout << arrSplited3[j] << " ";
    }
    return arrSplited3;
    delete [] arr3splitedStart, arrSplited3;
```

}

This surely is not the most ideal approach to this, this could be handled with a template function. I will work more on this.

How could this be more optimized ?